# visual c++ 2010 errors importing User32.dll into 64bit win7

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, 32bit-64bit

Running visual c++ 2010 on 64bit win7, this line

```
#include "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll"
```

its the correct path, the errors however include variations of

```
1>C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll(1): error C2018: unknown character '0x3'
1>C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll(1): error C2018: unknown character '0x4'
1>C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll(1): error C2018: unknown character '0x40'
1>C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll(1): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ÿÿ¸'
1>C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll(1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I am using it to get keybd_event() working as msdn says User32.dll is a requirement. Thanks !
*Note: The errors are in a code format block because it wouldn't let me submit it otherwise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how you import libraries. You just tried to include a binary. This has nothing to do with 32/64 bits.

What you need to do it add `user32.lib` to your library path.

You can import a library in Visual Studio by:

```
Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Additional Dependencies
```

Add "user32.lib" to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `#include <windows.h>` instead

Answer (score -1):

u load dll files by LoadLibrary() function which requires "windows.h" ,however visual studio add importatnt lib files like "user32.lib" and "kernal32.lib" etc  defaultly at run time,so u just have to include header file  to get that function work.