# How to solve a linker error with ExitWindowsEx in Windows.h

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker, c++-cli

I am recieving the following errors when I attempt to build and run my code in Visual Studio Express 2010:

```
1>  Generating Code...
1>Purple Health.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000035) "extern "C" int __stdcall ExitWindowsEx(unsigned int,unsigned long)" (?ExitWindowsEx@@$$J18YGHIK@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall PurpleHealth::FormOutOfTime::btnLogout_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?btnLogout_Click@FormOutOfTime@PurpleHealth@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>FormLauncher.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000031) "extern "C" int __stdcall ExitWindowsEx(unsigned int,unsigned long)" (?ExitWindowsEx@@$$J18YGHIK@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall PurpleHealth::FormOutOfTime::btnLogout_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?btnLogout_Click@FormOutOfTime@PurpleHealth@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>FormLauncher.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __stdcall ExitWindowsEx(unsigned int,unsigned long)" (?ExitWindowsEx@@$$J18YGHIK@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall PurpleHealth::FormOutOfTime::btnLogout_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?btnLogout_Click@FormOutOfTime@PurpleHealth@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Purple Health.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __stdcall ExitWindowsEx(unsigned int,unsigned long)" (?ExitWindowsEx@@$$J18YGHIK@Z)
1>C:\Users\Graham\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Purple Health\Debug\Purple Health.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

My code looks like this (With the unimportant bits edited out):

```
#include "FormParentalOverride.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include <iostream>
#using <System.dll>
#using <System.Windows.Forms.dll>
#using <System.Drawing.dll>
#pragma once

namespace PurpleHealth {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::IO;
    using namespace System::Text;

    public ref class FormOutOfTime : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    private: System::Void btnLogout_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 ExitWindowsEx(EWX_LOGOFF, SHTDN_REASON_MAJOR_APPLICATION);
                 //ExitWindows(0, 0);
             }
};
}
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add User32.dll to your link stage.

Note: Name is misleading inasmuch that the 64 and 32 bit versions are both called user32.

Comment: So would it be:
#using <User32.dll>

Comment: Found how to do it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642125/visual-c-2010-errors-importing-user32-dll-into-64bit-win7

Answer (score 1):

use #include< windows.h> instead of #include "Windows.h"