# Hello World program in Visual C++ giving errror

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've installed visual studio 2012. I wrote a simple "hello world" program in a new project. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
int _main()
{
    cout<<"Hello world";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

When the use of precompiled headers was on, I got error related to `stdafx.h` so I turned precompiled headers off and removed `#include stdafx.h`.

Now I get these strange error messages:

> - error C2018: unknown character '0x3'
> - error C2018: unknown character '0x4'
> - error C2018: unknown character '0x40'
> - error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ÿÿ¸'
> - error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

And many more similar errors causing the build to fail. The error is given by `cl.exe` to each and every line of the code.

Things I have tried so far:

- created an empty project with just 1 `.cpp` file including that code;
- tried using `std::cout`;
- tried using `int main()` instead of `int _main()`;
- tried `using namespace std`;
- tried the same things on Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: those 0x3 and 0x4 seem like you have copypasted or otherwise insert some invalid chars to your source file... And then you are at least missing `std::`, or more simply `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Also, why did you write `_main`, with underscore? Is it some Visual Studio thing?

Comment: **1.** Are you saying that you don't just get these 5 errors, you get them once per line of code, i.e. 7 x 5 errors = 35 errors in total? **2.** Do the errors *explicitly* refer to this `.cpp` file (the right one), or might the compiler try to compile the wrong file (i.e. receive an incorrect input file)?

Comment: This works: http://ideone.com/7ScNP4

Comment: Problem is not in anything you are showing (when taking your bulleted list into account). Need more information... You could update the code, and then show the actual compile output for the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Coding a consoleapplication in Viusal Studio and removing the include of the precompiled header gives you an error.
2. Look at your Linker-Properties (rightclick your project, select Properties and then select Linker - System). Be sure that you selected the SUBSYSTEM Console. Under Linker - Advanced you find your entry point. Be sure that your entry point = the name your main int.
3. Maybe look at this:
   [visual c++ 2010 errors importing User32.dll into 64bit win7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642125/visual-c-2010-errors-importing-user32-dll-into-64bit-win7)

Comment: I included stdafx.h and turned use of precompiled headers on. But I get the same errors with an additional error in the first line as                        error C2857: '#include' statement specified with the /YcStdAfx.h command-line option was not found in the source file

Comment: SUBSYSTEM console is selected by default, so i didn't change it. I didn't understand what should be the value of entry point in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I realized a strange thing. When I open VS and build for the first time, it builds successfully, but if I rebuild, it gives error.
  So each time I make a change in the code and compile, it gives the same errors. But if I close VS and open again and try, it works.